# Can all of Flex be configured via an API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking to configure Twilio Flex only via code without using the UI. However, I'm stuck trying to find out how to enable the dial pad and caller ID details along with a few other settings.

Is everything able to be configured via an API/Terraform?

[image]

How can I find out the missing parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit this information by Flex Configuration API.

Follow an example of a request that you can use:

**Request method**: POST

**Request URL**: https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/Configuration?UiVersion=1.30.2 (The UiVersion will be the version of your environment, in this example, the version of the Flex is 1.30.2)

**Authentication Type**: Basic

**Authentication credentials**: accountSid:authToken (accountSid is the username and authToken is the password)

**Request Body**:

```
{
"account_sid": "ACXXXX",
"outbound_call_flows": {
    "default": {
        "workflow_sid": "WWXXXX",
        "enabled": true,
        "queue_sid": "WQXXXX",
        "caller_id": "+551199998888",
        "location": "BR"
    }
}
```

- account_sid -> The Account's account_sid (ACXXXX)
- workflow_sid -> The Workflow that you want to configure for outbound calls, you can see existents workflows at Twilio Console following the path Taskrouter > Workspaces > Workflows (https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/taskrouter/workspaces?frameUrl=/console/taskrouter/workspaces) (WWXXX)
- queue_sid -> The Queue that you want to configure for outbound calls, you can see existents queues at Twilio Console following the path Taskrouter > Workspaces > Task Queues (https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/taskrouter/workspaces?frameUrl=/console/taskrouter/workspaces) (WQXXX)
- caller_id -> The Number that will be used for outbound calls, you can see the existents number at Twilio Console following the path Phone Numbers > Manage > Phone Numbers (https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/phone-numbers/manage/incoming) (+...)
- location -> The Location that will be used for outbound calls.

I hope that it can help you! :D

Comment: That’s great. Yep I have been changing stuff via that method. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment.